# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?user=root

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, mariadb

I've got this message when I try to connect to my DB. 
This is a web-app done with Eclipse and MariaDB.

```
package login.registration;

import java.sql.*;

public class MyConnectionProvider {

    private static Connection con = null;

    public static Connection dbConn() throws SQLException {

        // Connessione

        try {

            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        } // fine try/catch

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?user=root"); // aaa è il nome del DB

        return con;
    }

}
```

I've put Mysql connector java to the project lib (project is a new dynamic web project) and also MariaDB java client lib. 
Here is where I call the dbConn():

```
package login.registration;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class UtenteDAOImpl implements UtenteDAO {

    static Connection con;
    static Statement st;
    static ResultSet rs;

    @Override
    public int insertUtente(Utente user) {

        int status = 0;

        try {
            con = MyConnectionProvider.dbConn();
            st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO utenti (username,firstname,lastname,password,password2,email) VALUES ('"
                    + user.getUsername() + "','" + user.getFirstname() + "','"
                    + user.getLastname() + "','" + user.getPassword() + "','" + user.getPassword2() + "','"
                    + user.getEmail() + "')";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println(rs);
            con.close();
            status = 1;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public Utente getUtente(String username, String password) {

        Utente user = new Utente();
        try {

            con = MyConnectionProvider.dbConn();
            st=con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM UTENTI where username = " + username + " and password = " + password;
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                user.setUsername(rs.getString(1));
                user.setFirstname(rs.getString(2));
                user.setLastname(rs.getString(3));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString(4));
                user.setPassword2(rs.getString(5));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString(6));
            }
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

I connected my DB with XAMPP and the server to start my web-app is Tomcat 9.0. 
More or less, I followed the entire build of this app watching this video (if you need more info):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bl8UrkYbaU

So...How to fix this? Thanks in advance for your reply!!!

Comment: The JAR file with the JDBC driver must be either in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Intended of mysql connector use MariaDB Connector/J .jar from below address.

https://mariadb.com/downloads/#connectors